# Ionic ng-repeat returning one undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am attempting to filter a list of items the code below worded fine in angular js on the web but we can't expect Ionic to work now can we?

```
<ion-list *ngIf="items.length">
      {{items[0].title}}
      <ion-item ng-repeat="item in items | filter:searchLog">
        {{item == undefined}}
        <!--<ion-icon name="clipboard" item-left></ion-icon>
        <h2><b>Title: {{item.title}}</b></h2>
        <h3><b>Caller: {{item.caller.name}} - {{item.caller.number}}</b></h3>
        <h3><b>Location: {{item.caller.location}}</b></h3>
        <h3><i>Dispatcher: </i>{{item.dispatcher.name}} at {{item.timeStamp}}</h3>
        <h3><b>Dropped: {{item.canceled}}</b></h3>
        <h3 style="white-space: normal;"><i>Details:</i> {{item.details}}</h3>-->
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

This is what my screen shows:

```
car out of gas

true
```

For the life of me I cannot understand this because if I print `{{ items[0].title }}` it works fine in the repeat list meaning that it is not giving me this `item` object back from the ng-repeat call. What is even weirder is that `*ngFor` works but I cannot filter it :-( Please help

**TL;DR**: ng-repeat in angular is returning one undefined object.

Comment: what is `searchLog`?  seems like the filter is returning 0 results.

Comment: A string set by a bos on the top. I tried setting it to a valid search (e.g. the title of the first item but it did nothing

Comment: well, does the `ng-repeat` have values in it if you remove the `filter` clause? because it would seem like it should, if `*ngFor` is working....

Answer (score 0):

Use `*ngFor` with pipe (i.e. filter). If it is still not working then there is some problem with your pipe (filter). Code should look like below:

```
<ion-list *ngIf="items.length">
      {{items[0].title}}

     <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items | searchLog">

        <ion-icon name="clipboard" item-left></ion-icon>
        <h2><b>Title: {{item.title}}</b></h2>
        <h3><b>Caller: {{item.caller.name}} - {{item.caller.number}}</b></h3>
        <h3><b>Location: {{item.caller.location}}</b></h3>
        <h3><i>Dispatcher: </i>{{item.dispatcher.name}} at {{item.timeStamp}}</h3>
        <h3><b>Dropped: {{item.canceled}}</b></h3>
        <h3 style="white-space: normal;"><i>Details:</i> {{item.details}}</h3>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: checkout now. changed the template.

Comment: If it is still not working. please share your code snippet of pipe.

Comment: Sadly still returns one undefined object. I think it is the ionic framework. this would not be the first thing they broke in the name of insanity.